# Custom plugin getting conflict with divi theme. How to debug it?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just created a custom plugin for WordPress. In client's server, they used divi as there theme builder and it getting a conflict with my custom plugin.

How can I debug it? In my plugin, we are using bootstrap. Is this the conflict issue?

Comment: To debug it, you will need to get the exact same website's folder and debug in local.

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue bootstrap before the divi scripts, so you bootstrap doesn't overwrite divi design. You can use priority 1 to load before any divi scripts. 
If this doesn't help than you need to dequeue the scripts which are thrown before you bootstap and re-enqueu  on required order

Hope it works.